# Postgres Parent-Child row level security that can inherit from parents?

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

Child table that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE folder_item (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid()
    ,parent_id uuid REFERENCES folder_item (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    ,role text NOT NULL DEFAULT 'inherit'
);
```

With a permissions model

```
CREATE POLICY folder_item_rolecheck ON folder_item FOR SELECT USING ( role = assigned_role );
```

However if it finds a row with 'inherit' I want it to look at the parent role instead (recursively)

Is that possible?

Comment: what is "assigned_role" in "CREATE POLICY"

Comment: Just a placeholder for a userrole check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- Set NO FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY on table "folder_item" to off RLS for OWNER
ALTER TABLE folder_item NO FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY

-- Create function with RECURSIVE qwery and SECURITY DEFINER with OWNER as for table "folder_item"
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION folder_item_check_child(
    in_parent_id uuid
    , in_role text)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    STABLE SECURITY DEFINER 

AS $BODY$BEGIN
    RETURN EXISTS(
        WITH RECURSIVE 
        childs AS (
            SELECT tt.id, tt.role FROM folder_item AS tt 
            WHERE tt.parent_id=in_parent_id
            UNION 
            SELECT child.id, child.role 
            FROM childs AS parent 
            INNER JOIN folder_item AS child ON child.parent_id=parent.id  
        )
        SELECT * FROM childs AS tt WHERE tt.role=in_role
    );
END$BODY$;


-- CREATE POLICY
CREATE POLICY folder_item_rolecheck ON folder_item FOR SELECT USING ( role = assigned_role 

OR folder_item_check_child(id, assigned_role)  

);
```